# Eclipse - Set Execution preference between Java Application and TestNG

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a TestNG class file.

Whenever I try to execute it, I get the "Run As" options to select between Java Application and TestNG Test.

How do I default it to take always TestNG for this class file, whenever I execute it? Is there any association for class files to the way it has to run?

I've tried Window->Preferences->Run/Debug and in the Launch Operation -Setting it to option --> Always launch the previously launched application.

But, that doesn't solve my problem as that executes the previous launched application always even if I open another class file with a main to it.